# Decorated class looses acces to its attributes

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, class-attributes

I implemented a decorator that worked like a charm until I added attributes to the decorated class. When I instantiate the class, it cannot acces the calss attributes. Take the following minimal working example :

```
from module import specialfunction

class NumericalMathFunctionDecorator:
    def __init__(self, enableCache=True):
        self.enableCache = enableCache

    def __call__(self, wrapper):
        def numericalmathfunction(*args, **kwargs):
            func = specialfunction(wrapper(*args, **kwargs))
            """
            Do some setup to func with decorator arguments (e.g. enableCache)
            """
        return numericalmathfunction

@NumericalMathFunctionDecorator(enableCache=True)
class Wrapper:
    places = ['home', 'office']
    configs = {
               'home':
                  {
                   'attr1': 'path/at/home',
                   'attr2': 'jhdlt'
                  },
               'office':
                  {
                   'attr1': 'path/at/office',
                   'attr2': 'sfgqs'
                  }
              }
    def __init__(self, where='home'):
        # Look for setup configuration on 'Wrapper.configs[where]'.
        assert where in Wrapper.places, "Only valid places are {}".format(Wrapper.places)
        self.__dict__.update(Wrapper.configs[where])

    def __call__(self, X):
        """Do stuff with X and return the result
        """
        return X ** 2

model = Wrapper()
```

When I instantiate the Wrapper class (#1), I get the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a99bd3d544a3> in <module>()
     15         assert where in Wrapper.places, "Only valid places are {}".format(Wrapper.places)
     16 
---> 17 model = Wrapper()

<ipython-input-5-a99bd3d544a3> in numericalmathfunction(*args, **kwargs)
      5     def __call__(self, wrapper):
      6         def numericalmathfunction(*args, **kwargs):
----> 7             func = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
      8         return numericalmathfunction
      9 

<ipython-input-5-a99bd3d544a3> in __init__(self, where)
     13     def __init__(self, where='home'):
     14         # Look for setup configuration on 'Wrapper.configs[where]'.
---> 15         assert where in Wrapper.places, "Only valid places are {}".format(Wrapper.places)
     16 
     17 model = Wrapper()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'places'
```

I guess that with the decorator, Wrapper becomes a function that looses acces to its attributes...

Any ideas of how I can solve this ? Maybe there is a workaround

Comment: Why is your class decorator returning a function?

Comment: Wrapper is a function

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Wrapper is a callable class that later needs to be wrapper again by a `specialfunction`. I edited the example to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replaced `Wrapper` (which was a class) with the `numericalmathfunction` function object. That object doesn't have any of the class attributes, no.

In essence, the decorator does this:

```
class Wrapper:
    # ...

Wrapper = NumericalMathFunctionDecorator(enableCache=True)(Wrapper)
```

so whatever the `NumericalMathFunctionDecorator.__call__` method returns has now replaced the class; all references to `Wrapper` now reference that return value. And when you use the name `Wrapper` in the `__init__` method, you are referencing that global, not the original class.

You can still access the current class with `type(self)`, or just reference those attributes via `self` (where the name lookup falls through to the class):

```
def __init__(self, where='home'):
    # Look for setup configuration on 'Wrapper.configs[where]'.
    assert where in self.places, "Only valid places are {}".format(self.places)
    self.__dict__.update(self.configs[where])
```

or

```
def __init__(self, where='home'):
    # Look for setup configuration on 'Wrapper.configs[where]'.
    cls = type(self)
    assert where in cls.places, "Only valid places are {}".format(cls.places)
    self.__dict__.update(cls.configs[where])
```

In both cases you can end up with referencing an attribute on a subclass if you ever did subclass `Wrapper` (which you cannot do in this case anyway as you would have to fish the class out of the decorator closure).

Alternatively, you could store the original class as an attribute on the returned function:

```
def __call__(self, wrapper):
    def numericalmathfunction(*args, **kwargs):
        func = specialfunction(wrapper(*args, **kwargs))
        """
        Do some setup to func with decorator arguments (e.g. enableCache)
        """
    numericalmathfunction.__wrapped__ = wrapper
    return numericalmathfunction
```

then use that reference in your `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, where='home'):
    # Look for setup configuration on 'Wrapper.configs[where]'.
    cls = Wrapper
    while hasattr(cls, '__wrapped__'):
        # remove any decorator layers to get to the original
        cls = cls.__wrapped__
    assert where in cls.places, "Only valid places are {}".format(cls.places)
    self.__dict__.update(cls.configs[where])
```

Comment: Using self.places solves the problem. However, I just bumped into another one. In the `__init__` method, I also invoke the `__init__` of the base clase: `super(Wrapper, self).__init__(4, 1)` and it throws `TypeError: must be type, not function`. I will try your last solution to see what it does

Comment: @FelipeAguirre: again, `Wrapper` is the global name. Using `type(self)` would actually be very wrong there as that'll break when subclassing, the best option would be to use the `__wrapped__` attribute option in that case.

Comment: Ok, I tried it, but it returns a `NoneType`. (Just the `__init__` as you defined it without adding the `super(cls.__wrapped__).__init__(4, 1)`)

Comment: @FelipeAguirre: *what* returns `None`?

Comment: Instantiating the class Wrapper

Comment: @FelipeAguirre: that'd be your `numericalmathfunction()` function not returning anything then. When you use `Wrapper()` you are really calling `numericalmathfunction()`, so if that function doesn't return anything you get `None`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79968/discussion-between-felipe-aguirre-and-martijn-pieters).