# Why does a decorated class looses its docstrings?

Tags: python, python-decorators, docstring

I'm currently implementing an API on which I need to decorate the class `Wrapper`, but I want it to keep its docstring to make it available to the API user. Take a look at the following minimal working example :

```
class ClassDecorator:
    """ClassDecorator docstring
    """
    def __init__(self, enableCache=True):
        self.enableCache = enableCache

    def __call__(self, wrapper):
        def numericalmathfunction(*args, **kwargs):
            func = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
            return func
        return numericalmathfunction

@ClassDecorator(enableCache=True)
class Wrapper(object):
    """Wrapper docstring
    Instructions on how to use the Wrapper
    """
    def __init__(self, p):
        self.p = p

model = Wrapper(4)
print model.__doc__
print Wrapper.__doc__
```

This returns

```
Wrapper docstring
None
```

Instances of `Wrapper` do keep the docstring, which is fine, but `Wrapper` itself does not. If a user wants to learn how to use `Wrapper` using `help(Wrapper)`, he won't get what he wants.

I know I could just copy paste the dosctring into `numericalmathfunction`, but the decorator will be used on several classes with different docstrings.

Any ideas on how to make `numericalmathfunction` systematically inherit the docstrings of the wrapped class ?

Comment: Because the wrapper is now technically the class that is being called first.  Look into `@wraps` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `functools.wraps()` to update the attributes of the decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

class ClassDecorator:
    """ClassDecorator docstring
    """
    def __init__(self, enableCache=True):
        self.enableCache = enableCache

    def __call__(self, wrapper):
        @wraps(wrapper)                              # <-----------
        def numericalmathfunction(*args, **kwargs):
            func = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
            return func
        return numericalmathfunction

@ClassDecorator(enableCache=True)
class Wrapper(object):
    """Wrapper docstring
    Instructions on how to use the Wrapper
    """
    def __init__(self, p):
        self.p = p
```

See more standard library documentation for [functools.wrap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

Comment: Great, it works. Is there a similar solution so that the decorated function inherits class attributes? I already found a solution to this (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711730/decorated-class-looses-acces-to-its-attributes)), but I was wondering if there is something of the likes of `@wraps`.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You can easily write a wrapper decorator based on the answer in that link and use it everywhere. That should work the same way as `@wraps`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that later on to make the code more elegant. For the moment, I already have a working solution. Thanks

Comment: @FelipeAguirre For some great examples of this type of work, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPiWg5jSoZI).  The first 30 minutes especially.

Comment: I'll give it a look, but I'm still stuck with python 2 and the tutorial is for python 3. :(